# Вывод значений по запросу пользователя используя Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, dom

Всем привет. Срочно нужна помощь.

Есть xml документ

```
<remakes>
<remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
<ryear>1938</ryear>
<fraction>0.5</fraction>
<stitle>Pygmalion</stitle>
<syear>1937</syear>
</remake>
<remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
<ryear>1938</ryear>
<fraction>0.2</fraction>
<stitle>Twentieth Century</stitle>
<syear>1934</syear>
</remake>
```

Нужно создать страницу, чтобы пользователь должен иметь возможность вводить значение (например, 1990), а также оператор (<, = или> для года и доли, но только = для заголовка) и извлекать фильмы, удовлетворяющие соответствующим условиям (например, ryear = 1990). Пока-что вот стадия разработки, на которой я застрял:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("Document element is: <em>",
            getXML("rss-fragment.xml").documentElement.nodeName,
            "</em>");
        </script>
        function getXML('remakes.xml') {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", 'remakes.xml', false);
            xhr.send(null);
            return xhr.responseXML;
        }
        </script>
        <title>MyRemakes</title>
    </head>

        <body>
        The content of the document......
        </body>

</html>
```

Вот попытки создать кнопку ввода:

```
//user input event
<form>
    <label>Enter a word:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myWord" />
    <input type"button" value="Search"
        onClick="myResult.value=mySearch(myWord.value)" />
    <input type="text" id="myResult" />
<form>
```

Я окончательно запутался... как сделать так, чтобы код соответствовал задаче? Буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то я разошёлся:

```js
let data = `<remakes>
<remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
<ryear>1938</ryear>
<fraction>0.1</fraction>
<stitle>Pygmalion</stitle>
<syear>1937</syear>
</remake>
<remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion2</rtitle>
<ryear>1936</ryear>
<fraction>0.5</fraction>
<stitle>Twentieth Century</stitle>
<syear>1934</syear>
</remake><remake>
<rtitle>Pygmalion3</rtitle>
<ryear>1935</ryear>
<fraction>0.3</fraction>
<stitle>Twentieth Century</stitle>
<syear>1931</syear>
</remake></remakes>`,
  parser = new DOMParser(),
  dom = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml"); // Парсим XML в DOM

document.querySelector('#searchBtn').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  let params = {};

  // Выдираем из ячеек значения в объект вида: {rtitle: {text: "some", sel: "=", skip: false},...}
  // text - текст фильтра
  // sel  - селектор сравнения
  // skip - чтобы считать пустые фильтры подходящими
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#table tr')).forEach(el => {
    let tmp = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('td'));
    let [name, text, sel] = [tmp[0].innerText, +tmp[1].children[0].value ? +tmp[1].children[0].value : tmp[1].children[0].value.trim(), tmp[2].children[0].selectedOptions[0].innerText];
    
    params[name.toLowerCase()] = {
      text,
      sel,
      skip: '' + text === ''
    };

  });

  search(params);
});

function search(params) {
  let found = [];
  
  // Обходим все элементы в XML DOM
  Array.from(dom.querySelectorAll('remakes > remake')).forEach(item => {
    // Вес текущего объекта
    // Если будет равен пяти (т. е. все поля выдали true) - считаем что этот объект подходит под фильтр
    let yeah = 0;

    // Проверяем все поля очередного remake
    Array.from(item.children).forEach(_ => {
      // config - объект для текущего поля (тот, который с text, sel и skip)
      // value  - значение проверяемого поля
      let [config, value] = [params[_.tagName.toLowerCase()], +_.innerHTML ? +_.innerHTML : _.innerHTML];

      // Если поле нужно одобрить без проверки - пропускаем (добавляем вес)
      if(config.skip){
        yeah++;
      }else{
        // Очевидно же - по селектору сравниваем и, если подходит, добавляем вес
        switch(config.sel){
          case '=':
            config.text === value ? yeah++ : null;
            break;
          case '>':
            config.text < value ? yeah++ : null;
            break;
          case '<':
            config.text > value ? yeah++ : null;
            break;
        }
      }
    });

    // Если вес подходящий, добавляем в отфильтрованные
    if (yeah == 5)
      found.push(item);
  });

  render(found);
}

/**
 * Отображает результат
 *
 * @param Element[] items remake-элементы
 */
function render(items){
  document.querySelector('#myResult').innerHTML = items.length ? items.map(e => `<p>${Array.from(e.children).reduce((s, e) => s += `<div>${e.innerHTML}</div>`, '')}</p>`).join('<hr />') : '<h3>No items found</h3>';
}
```

```html
<h3>Enter your selectors:</h3>
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>rtitle</td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><select><option>=</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ryear</td>
    <td><input type='text' />
      <td><select><option>=</option><option>></option><option><</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fraction</td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><select><option>=</option><option>></option><option><</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>stitle</td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><select><option>=</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>syear</td>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><select><option>=</option><option>></option><option><</option></select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Search" id='searchBtn' /><br />
<div id="myResult"></div>
```